# jQuery Validation - Dynamic forms

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, dynamic

I have the same form as on http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/dynamic-totals.html
Only for the dropdown (select) I use an input field. The second option in the addMethod is about the select but I wanted to check the input.

```
$.validator.addMethod("quantity", function(value, element) {
    return !this.optional(element) && !this.optional($(element).parent().prev().children("select")[0]);
}, "Please select both the item and its amount.");
```

I'v tried ...

```
return !this.optional(element) && !this.optional($(element).parent().prev().children("input")[0]);
```

but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return !this.optional(element) && ($(element).parent().prev().find("input").val().length>0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/291oy2v2/2/